# Pulling CPU arch agnostic Docker images

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, arm

Docker hub notes which CPU arch it supports (amd64, arm32v5, arm32v6, arm32v7, arm64v8 etc). However it seems I need to specify arch-specific image name in order to use them.

For example `busybox:latest` pulls amd64 ([link](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox)) instead of my current arch. I'm on Raspberry PI (arm32v7) and its image is under the user `arm32v7` ([link](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/busybox/)) so the image name would be `arm32v7/busybox:latest`.

This implies that I need to create different configs (e.g. docker-compose or k8s deployment file) for each arch if I want to run my container on multiple arch'es. I'd like to have a single config that hides arch differences and hopefully there exist a way for Docker to pull arch specific images depending on where Docker engine is running.

Is this possible?

Here are some output of my environment.

#### `docker version`

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:37:22 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:31:17 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

#### `docker info`

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 41
  Running: 20
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 21
 Images: 17
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.75-v7l+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.814GiB
 Name: raspberrypi
 ID: EDO4:EH5V:KIKR:WJE7:VQX4:FXZA:VROQ:3EE3:FEOU:42Q5:TXKI:3HPX
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

#### `uname -a`

`Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7l+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:51:41 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: These two are completely unrelated (in the docker sense), different containers. It's unclear what you ask. If you ask how to "pull arch specific images depending on where Docker engine", it's up to you to script it, not on docker side. Docker does not see architecture that much, for docker these are just files.`arm32v7/busybox` image is made by `arm32v7`, it's different from the official `busybox`.

Comment: @KamilCuk. Perhaps Busybox was a bad example. I don't know much of what it does except that I need this container as a dependency and was running into arch difference issues. Say Postgres container. Functionality of Postgres should be almost identical across architectures regardless of it's installed in x86 or ARM based machines. Yes, I could write a script to pull the right image but it's odd to me that that's handled by the user not the Docker engine. Specifying arch seems like depending on implementation rather than interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker supports multiarch (multiplatform) images. But it needs native multiarch images, which need more complicated docker build process. If image has multiarch support, then Docker pulls correct architecture based on the local architecture.

Usually, base official OS images have already implemented multiarch support - https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-official-images-now-multi-platform/

However, majority of Docker images supports only single architecture.

Actually, `busybox` is multiarch image:

```
$ docker manifest inspect busybox | grep -E ".*(architecture|variant).*"
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "architecture": "arm",
            "variant": "v5"
            "architecture": "arm",
            "variant": "v6"
            "architecture": "arm",
            "variant": "v7"
            "architecture": "arm64",
            "variant": "v8"
            "architecture": "386",
            "architecture": "ppc64le",
            "architecture": "s390x",
```

But your architecture (`arm32v7` - maybe it is `armv7`) is not available there - it will pull default `amd64` version. So this image needs small improvement to support also your architecture.